# sending alerts from linux machine through email to MS outlook exchange

Tags: linux, rhel, sendmail, mail-command

I Have a Scenario. I have written a shell script who check the space of mount point '/u06'. if free space is greater then 20% then its OK or if free space is less then 20% then it should generate a mail and send it to System Administrator. Our organization is using MS Outlook mailing. I want to know how can I send alerts through my Linux machine to exchange server. How to configure email in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of different ways, but basically, you just need a mail program that supports SMTP and has a CLI. One option is ssmtp `yum install ssmtp` Then edit `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` to use your mail server. [SSMTP - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP#Forward_to_a_Gmail_mail_server) has a good sample configuration. Test it. Then, something like `echo "Disk full" | ssmtp -s "Alert" to@somedomain.com`

Assess any security issues. The ArchWiki touches on it a bit. I also recommend creating an email account solely for this purpose (e.g., machinename-notifications@somedomain.com).

Comment: Of course this is only going to work if [SMTP Authentication is enabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission) for the Outlook accounts in question (which MS now actively discourages). If it isn't, and you can't convince your admin to enable it, you'd be stuck writing a Graph API client app or something like that.

Comment: @frabjous that's not necessarily true. If the domain for the service accounts isn't owned by exchange, then linux machines can send email in through the front door, just like any third party email host. That involves no authentication.